# Cannot delete the checkbox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to select the check box in datasheet view then click delete button to delete the data and got this error...I don't know what is the problem?...I have trying the coding

```
Dim strsql as string 

strsql = "DELETE * FROM mytablename WHERE delete = YES" 
Docmd.Runsql strsql
end sub
```

Are the coding right or wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you really need an unbound form with a command button. Clicking the command button would generate a message box function. Click YES to that and your data is deleted.

1. You create a form using the “Create Form” Wizard but do not connect it to a table or query. When you are creating the form, go to Form Properties, Data tab. Leave “Record Source” Blank.

I imagine your table might have a field called say “DelRec”. This would be a “Yes/No”.

2. You create a SELECT query thus: (This is in Design View) (Named Query1 in this example)

   SELECT MyTableName.*, MyTableName.DelRec
   FROM MyTableName
   WHERE (((MyTableName.DelRec)=True));
3. You create an unbound form With a command button on.

The On Click Event would be:

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

Dim Wrng As Integer

DoCmd.OpenQuery "Query1"

Wrng = MsgBox("Are you sure you want to delete these records?",     vbExclamation + vbDefaultButton2 + vbYesNo, "Warning Title")

If Wrng = 6 Then
        DoCmd.Close acQuery, "Query1"
        DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE MyTableName.*, MyTableName.DelRec " & _
                     "FROM MyTableName " & _
                     "WHERE (((MyTableName.DelRec)=True)) "
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: How to create an unbound form?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `YES` is not a valid value. Did you mean `True` or, `"Yes"`?
Secondly, if it worked you'd need to refresh the form.

Comment: I mean "Yes"..and it's work on Access 2007 and after I copy and paste to Access 2010..it did not work..